# Save form data from another server

Tags: php, mysql, forms, facebook-apps

I have simple Facebook app done right now (HTML+JS). User can just click and see some pages/products there but now I would like to add also form where they can leave their information (name + email). The app is currently hosted on my web partner server and I would like to still keep it there but where the information would be saved in future would be on different server. Now I'm worried about the security side. What is the best way to send the form data to another server php, process there and save it db? If this is even possible (should be). I'm more designer guy so I feel bit uncertain when comes PHP and personal information.

So make it short: Facebook app (HTML+JS) that is hosted on Server1. Server2 where I have database and where I would like to save the form data. Or would it be just easiest to move the whole app to server2 too?

Comment: Why would not just keep the app/code on 1 server and just store it to the database on another server?

Comment: Some contract/money things just, so that would preferred way.

Comment: If it's non sensitive info. You could handle a form with `POST` and build a redirect url with `GET`. Then send it to a different domain or server.
If the info is sensitive handle the form save it to a db and then retrieve the data on a different server from the same database.

Comment: @TomKriek `. If the info is sensitive handle the form save it to a db and then retrieve the data on a different server from the same database` - Why would you do this? Just make sure you are working secure(SSL).

Comment: For starters I'd rather not pass around password and pincodes in GET. When working with sensitive data an encryption of some sorts is advised/recommended. Imagine that a friend of yours is using the computer on the same site and types in the url of that site. Then the full link might pop up with GET variables in them. Hence if it's only parameters to determine an action on the next page it would be ok.

Comment: The data that would need to send from form is peoples name + email. No credit card/password informations.

Comment: @TomKriek Your comment is correct, but not answering my question. ps. Use '@' + username so that the user gets a notification.

Comment: @GuyT It's one of the ways I would approach a problem of transferring data from one domain/server to another. In this case it was listed to transfer it via database. You suggested SSL. In the end you can make it as safe as you desire. There isn't much incentive in overcomplicating programming. Setting up SSL certificates for maybe a multiple server environment can be tricky and might not be worth the effort. Maybe the OP doesn't have full access to the server. Too little data to give a full 100% working accesible, understandable solution.

Comment: @TomKriek I agree with you, but to save it to a database and connect from another server to this database(in many situations not even possible) is a bit overkill IMO.

Comment: @GuyT There is a reason why I'm posting my suggestions in comments first before typing them out in an answer. Might have been better to ask the OP for more info to give him a better answer and I might have jumped the gun, but I hope you realize I'm just trying to think along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP on your first Server to write the data into your database on your second Server (using the correct connection). Then when you move your Website to the second server all your data will already be there and you wont need to move anything. If your second server is not yet available you can write the data to a database on your first server. Then when you want to move it to your second server you can export the database from your first server and import it on your second server. Then you will have to change your php to connect to the database on your second server.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking. But what you mean by using "the correct connection"? And I think my main question in the end, is this safe way do it? Sending stuff to another server.

Comment: I mean that you will need to specify in your PHP code which server to connect to and on the server with the database you will need to allow a connection to be made from your other sever. As far as security is concerned this is just as safe as when the database is on the same server as the site.

Comment: You can allow external connections in your configuration. Allow the 2nd server to connect to the database where you have your data stored. If you are using mysqli_* for instance you can create two connections and use them both in the same code.

Comment: Excelent. Thanks guys. This clears things up for me.